# List Authors For Current Category

Tags: posts, categories, loop, list-authors

I want to list all unique authors that have posts in the current category.

My code (location: wp-content/themes/custom-theme/category.php)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_author(); ?>

            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <?php the_author_meta( 'display_name', 30 ); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php else: ?>

        <p class="text-center">No authors</p>

      <?php endif; ?>

     </div>
</div>
```

This is not giving expected result, can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have a user with `ID` of 30?

Comment: Yes, that was just a test. I don't need that, I need to display all authors in that category. I am getting back something similar to infinite loop... Without names...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execution of code goes to infinite loop because you missed `the_post()` in loop.

You can list all authors from current category:-

- Create an empty array for author IDs
- Check if current author ID exist in that array
- If No, display the author name and store that author ID in array.
- If Yes, Then skip that post and move to next.

Consider this example:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"><?php 

        if ( have_posts() ) { 
            $unique_authors = array();

            while( have_posts() ) { 
                the_post(); ?>

                <div class="col-md-2 text-center"><?php
                    if (!in_array(get_the_author_meta('ID'), $unique_authors)) {
                        the_author_meta( 'display_name' );
                        array_push($unique_authors, get_the_author_meta('ID'));
                    } ?>
                </div><?php 

            }
        } else { ?>
            <p class="text-center">No authors</p><?php
        } ?>

     </div>
</div>
```